# Redirect STDIN to socket and socket to STDOUT

Tags: c, sockets, file-descriptor

I am trying to develop a simple command-line client to the server. After I connect to the server and setup everything correctly I want to redirect `STDIN` to the socket connected to the server and the same socket to `STDOUT`. I want to achieve behavior similar to the of `nc` tool.

The most simple solution would be use `select()` and use `read()`/`write()` to pass data from `STDIN` to the socket and from the socket to `STDOUT`.

Is there any other simpler way to somehow connect socket to to the `STDIN`/`STDOUT?` I thought about using `dup2()` system call. However, I am not sure how to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to keep stdin open and copy data from stdin to the socket, and copy data from the socket to stdout? dup won't help you with that..

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: `dup2` is useless in that context!

Comment: @salva uh why is that?

Comment: @LtWorf: becauses `dup2` doesn't move data between file descriptors that is what the OP wants to do. It just assigns the same file object from some file descriptor to another one.

Comment: And by doing so, the process will use the socket as stdin/stdout, which is what the op asked for.

Comment: @LtWorf: I don't think you are understanding the OP problem correctly. Mostly, he is trying to reimplement `netcat` so his program has to read from stdin and write the data through the socket and conversely read from the socket and write to stdout.

Comment: aaaaaaaaah! It makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux you can use `splice(2)` to move data between file descriptors at the kernel level. Though, you would still have to use `select(2)` (or equivalent) to handle the two directions in parallel or alternatively use two threads.

Comment: He can just fork the server, dup the socket to stdin/stdout/stderr, and exec a shell, there is no need for all that.

Comment: @LtWorf: there is no shell to `exec`!

Comment: Thanks. There is no `splice(2)` on FreeBSD. Is it equivalent to `sendfile(2)`?

Comment: @MichalPietras: The man page for FreeBSD `sendfile(2)` says that the target FD must be a socket, so you would be able to use it to move data between stdin and the socket but not between the socket and stdout.

Comment: @salva why if there's a shell, it doesn't require the select(2) involved?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to do the protocol handshaking in your program and, once the socket is ready, exec a program as `socat` to perform the data forwarding.

For instance, call `dup2` to copy the socket into file descriptor 3, unset its close-on-exec flag and then exec `socat STDIO FD:3`.

Comment: What is `socat`? I don't see anything like this in FreeBSD.

Comment: @MichalPietras: [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/). I am sure it is available from FreeBSD ports collection.